# How to use font icon (font-awesome) in XML selector

Tags: android, xml, font-awesome

Is it possible to use font icon in selector instead of drawable ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_home_press" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_home"></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed text color in selector instead of drawable. 
Its working fine.

Create MyTextView class which extends TextView

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Create text_color_selector.xml selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#ff0000" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="#ff0000" android:state_focused="true" />
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#000000" />
    <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

And then use it in you layout

```
 <com.example.mohsin.myapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector"
        android:text="\uF242">

    </com.example.mohsin.myapplication.MyTextView>
```

Answer (score 3):

**The easiest way!**

Since Android Support Library 26 and Android Studio 3.0 you can use native fonts support in XML.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

1. Create font directory in res directory
2. Copy font file into font directory
3. Create new Font resource file near font file

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <font
           android:font="@font/font_awesome_font"
           android:fontStyle="normal"
           android:fontWeight="400"
           app:font="@font/font_awesome_font"
           app:fontStyle="normal"
           app:fontWeight="400" />
   </font-family>
   ```

   Use `android:font` for API 26 and `app:font` for support API since 14.
4. Now you can use `fontFamily` in `TextView`:

   ```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:fontFamily="@font/font_awesome"
       android:text="\uF0da" />
   ```
5. To insert font-awesome char enter it UTF code with `\u`

**NOTE:** Android Studio design preview doesn't display font-awesome char but in application it works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use font-awesome icons as follows :

1 - Copy font-awesome font file to your assets directory

2 - Found the character entities for icons I wanted, using [this](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) page

3 - Create entry in strings.xml for each icon. Eg:

```
<string name="icon_eg">&#xf13d;</string>
```

4 - Load the font in onCreate method and set it for the appropriate Views:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
...
Button button = (Button)findViewById( R.id.like );
button.setTypeface(font);
```

Don't forget to reference the string in view.

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/my_btn"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     ...
     android:text="@string/icon_eg" />
```

check [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-fontawesome-in-an-android-app--cms-24167) link for more info.

you can't use it as selector. but you can dynamically change the icons.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but i want to use in selector instead of simple icon

Comment: that is not possible, since it is font (text).